# Show/hide forms using buttons and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show a form using a button, and hide it when the user presses another button, because the other button shows another form. I did a similar thing with a select box, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Everyone is going to ask you what you've tried already because nobody here wants to do your work from scratch. It makes us feel all warm and fuzzy inside when we see that you have tried at least as hard as we have in providing you with an answer.

Comment: Nice one... I tried writing a Javascript function similiar to the one with the select box thingy, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I'll figure it out.

Comment: @antyrat: -10 for linking to your own site that kills the back button functionality!  ;)

Comment: @Limey This is not my site ;)

Comment: OT; @Limey What do you mean by "kill the back button functionality"? It works as expected (using Opera 12 @ Ubuntu).

Comment: @feeela: from the status bar, it looks like its trying to do something with facebook when you hit the back button. It did finally work once for me, but then started failing again in IE 8 (yes, yes, i know, but its work, so I am forced).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the following code fragment to hide the form on button click.

```
document.getElementById("your form id").style.display="none";
```

And the following code to display it:

```
document.getElementById("your form id").style.display="block";
```

Or you can use the same function for both purposes:

```
function asd(a)
{
    if(a==1)
        document.getElementById("asd").style.display="none";
    else
        document.getElementById("asd").style.display="block";
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form id="asd">form </form>
<button onclick="asd(1)">Hide</button>
<button onclick="asd(2)">Show</button>
```

Comment: I'd use jQuery instead. Everything else became to unsecure to me.

Comment: Can you do that on the form level, or do you need to wrap your form in a div?

Comment: yeah but it answers his question in simple js right!! if the answer is wrong then downvote it else there seems no reason why it wont answer the question.

Comment: there is no problem to do it form level

Comment: Aren't the two `button` elements required to be inside the `form` HTML element? Is it well-formed HTML?

Answer (score 5):

There's something I bet you already heard about this! It's called [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#form1").show();
};
```

It's really easy and you can use CSS-like selectors and you can add animations. It's really easy to learn.

Comment: -1 Really, you would load the whole library for this simple functionality

Comment: You're allways going to use jQuery.

Comment: +1 as I'm sure he has other things going on in his web application that could make use of JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a container and two sub containers, you can do like this

jQuery

```
    $("#previousbutton").click(function() {
    $("#form_sub_container1").show();
    $("#form_sub_container2").hide(); })

    $("#nextbutton").click(function() {
    $("#form_container").find(":hidden").show().next();
    $("#form_sub_container1").hide();
})
```

HTML

```
     <div id="form_container">
            <div id="form_sub_container1" style="display: block;">
            </div>

            <div id="form_sub_container2" style="display: none;">
            </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you want the same form with different parts, showing each part accordingly with a button?

Here an example with three steps, that is, three form parts, but it is expandable to any number of form parts. The HTML characters `&laquo;` and `&raquo;` just print respectively « and » which might be interesting for the previous and next button characters.

```js
shows_form_part(1)

/* this function shows form part [n] and hides the remaining form parts */
function shows_form_part(n){
  var i = 1, p = document.getElementById("form_part"+1);
  while (p !== null){
    if (i === n){
      p.style.display = "";
    }
    else{
      p.style.display = "none";
    }
    i++;
    p = document.getElementById("form_part"+i);
  }
}

/* this is called at the last step using info filled during the previous steps*/
function calc_sum() {
  var sum =
    parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value) +
    parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value) +
    parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);

  alert("The sum is: " + sum);
}
```

```html
<div id="form_part1">
  Part 1<br>
  <input type="number" value="1" id="num1"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&raquo;</button>
</div>

<div id="form_part2">
  Part 2<br>
  <input type="number" value="2" id="num2"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(1)">&laquo;</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(3)">&raquo;</button>
</div>

<div id="form_part3">
  Part 3<br>
  <input type="number" value="3" id="num3"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&laquo;</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="calc_sum()">Sum</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the global attribute called `hidden`. But I'm green to all this and maybe there was a reason it wasn't mentioned yet?

```js
var someCondition = true;

if (someCondition == true){
    document.getElementById('hidden div').hidden = false;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden div" hidden>
    stuff hidden by default
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, it worked like a charm