# Hide Form in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to hide a form after the submit button is clicked. I have googled and followed some but they seem to be not working for me.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<form name="regForm" id="regForm" action="indexSave.php" method="post">

<table width="100%" border="0">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <center> Registration Form </center> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="23%">&nbsp; Name</td>
    <td width="33%">&nbsp; <input type="text" name="name"  /> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; Email Address</td>
    <td>&nbsp;  <input type="text" name="email"  /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; Contact Number</td>
    <td>&nbsp;  <input type="text" name="number"  /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; Message</td>
    <td width="100">&nbsp; <textarea name="msg"> </textarea> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;  <input onclick="myClick()" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  /> </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myClick() 
    {
        var me = document.getElementById("wrapper").visibility="false";
    }
</script>
```

I also tried this (from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226489/show-hide-forms-using-buttons-and-javascript) )

```
var me = document.getElementById("regForm").style.display="none";
```

Please help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Either of the answers below will work. Just to clear one thing up though... the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property should be either `'visible'` or `'hidden'` rather than a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need:

```
function myClick(){
     var form = document.getElementById("regForm");
     form.style.display = "none";
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/KbjEL/)**

Comment: Thank you. I think my php is messing up with the javascript. It doesn't want to hide the form. >.<

Comment: yap. its the php. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

If hiding is all you want, you can have it with this really tiny piece of code:

```
<form onsubmit="this.style.display='none'" name="regForm" id="regForm" action="indexSave.php" method="post">
```

It will also hide the form when [enter] is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

This code hides the form, reorganizing the other elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = document.getElementById("regForm");    
    function myClick(){
        form.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

This code only makes it invisible, so if the code above is messing the layout, use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = document.getElementById("regForm");    
    function myClick(){
        form.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("regForm").style.display="none";
```

is enough to hide `regForm`. Try to place your `<script>` in `<head>`.

Comment: its in the head. i think the problem now is that my php is messing with the javascript