# call javascript a function in html submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which I want to hide or show dependent on the users decision. I got following functions in an external javascript file:

```
function hide_element() { 
    $("form").hide(); 
};

function show_element() {
    $("form").show();
};
```

and this is how I call those functions:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="show_element;">show</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="hide_element;">hide</button>
<form>
...
</form>
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Do you have any clues why this is the case?

Comment: replace this show_element; with show_element() & hide_element; with hide_element()

Comment: Have you include jQuery lib in your HTML ?

Comment: I found something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226489/show-hide-forms-using-buttons-and-javascript 

Hope it helps?

Comment: this `$("form")` indicates that you are using `jQuery` my friend :) but I see your problems are solved.

Comment: @ZedWhatSheSaid The answer you marked as solves is terrible and bad practice.

Comment: @ZedWhatSheSaid You should really reconsider.. I wrote a nice answer to this question below, highlighting some of the bad practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Since we are using `jQuery` I would like to propose this approach:**

**HTML:**

```
<button id='toggleMyForm'>hide</button>
<form id='myForm'>First name:
    <br>
    <input type=" text " name="firstname " />
    <br>Last name:
    <br>
    <input type="text " name="lastname " />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var myForm       = $('#myForm');
var toggleMyForm = $('#toggleMyForm');

toggleMyForm.on('click', function(){
    myForm.toggle();
    myForm.is(":visible") ? $(this).html('hide') : $(this).html('show');
});
```

> **Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/obm39uus/**

---

> NOTE: don't put yourself in the position where you have multiple `submit` buttons in a `<form>`, you can distinguish between them by using `value` attribute, but still in my opinion it's better to keep clean design with one submit per form.
>
> don't repeat `jQuery` fetching calls. make a handle of a element:
> `var myForm = $('myForm');` then use it like this e.g: `myForm.show()`

Answer (score 5):

replace show_element with show_element() & hide_element with hide_element() like below:

```
  <button type="submit" onclick="show_element();">show</button>
  <button type="submit" onclick="hide_element();">hide</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you try to call variables named `show_element` and `hide_element`. These doesn't exist.

Function has to be called with brackets. If you have no params, use `()`.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="show_element();">show</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="hide_element();">hide</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `<button type="button" class="hide">Hide</button>`

And, in the js file :

```
$('button.hide').click(function() {
    $('form').hide();
}
```

Same thing for the show button.

Answer (score 1):

is this pseudo-code?

If not I would rewrite it like:

```
$form = $('#form_id');

function hide_element() {
    $form.hide();
    $form.submit();
}

function show_element() {
    $form.show();
    $form.submit();
}
```

And then:

```
<button onclick="show_element();">show</button>
<button onclick="hide_element();">hide</button>
<form>
...
</form>
```

I removed the type submit because it is not good to have more than one submit. Actually both are outside the form. In case you want to submit it I would put it like this:

```
<button onclick="show_element();">show</button>
<button onclick="hide_element();">hide</button>
<form>
...
</form>
```

Comment: This is bad. One `submit` action per form is a good practice.  You also unnecessarily  call  `$('#form_id')` 4x times instead of making a handle to the object.

Comment: Yes, right. A handler would make it better. I edit it. I don't get why are you saying this about the submit's. I said it is not a good idea to have more than one submit per form.

Answer (score 1):

You've to replace "show_element;" with "show_element();".

```
 <button type="submit" onclick="show_element();">show</button>
 <button type="submit" onclick="hide_element();">hide</button>
```

But why? 
The () Operator Invokes the Function.
Using the example above, show_element refers to the function object, and show_element() refers to the function result.

Example:

Accessing a function without () will return the function definition:

```
function toCelsius(fahrenheit) {
    return (5/9) * (fahrenheit-32);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toCelsius;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

With "show_element" you are able to store the function itself (in a variable for example), but you don't execute it.