# How to show and hide a form?

Tags: javascript

When I load a page, I need to show  form for name, but when I click "submit" i need hide that form. How can i do that with javascript?

```
<div id="small-form">
    <form>
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="hideForm()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you wish to permanently hide the form for the current session, or you wish to toggle the visibility of the form?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226489/show-hide-forms-using-buttons-and-javascript this is the answer you were looking for?

Comment: I do this for the quiz and I have to take the name at the beginning and  hide the form, at the end of the quiz I will print the name from the form and points

Answer (score 0):

In the `hideForm()` function set `display:none` style for the div `small-form`.

Like that:

```
var myFormDiv = document.getElementById("small-form");
myFormDiv.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just hide the form if it submits to the server unless you either Ajax the form to the server or target an iframe or new tab

When the form submits, a new page is loaded. If it loads the same page, you can either hide it on the server or set an instruction in localStorage to tell the page to not show the form

I also strongly suggest you do NOT use onclick of a submit button but the submit event

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // if you want to NOT submit the form
  document.getElementById("small-form").classList.add("hide");
//  here you can ajax or do other stuff without submitting
})
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="small-form">
    <form id="myForm">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to permanently hide the form you can do something like this. Just set the `display` property of the form to `none`. This will hide the form but it will exist there in the HTML code.

```js
function hideForm() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myForm = document.getElementById("My-Form");
    myForm.style.display = "none";
    var name = document.getElementById("Name");
    alert(name.value);
}
```

```html
<div id="small-form">
    <form id="My-Form">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input id="Name" type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="hideForm(event)">
    </form>
</div>
```

Another way to achieve what you are trying to do is simply remove the form. You can do this by calling `remove()` function on the form. This permanently removes the form.

```js
function hideForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myForm = document.getElementById("My-Form");
    var name = document.getElementById("Name");
    alert(name.value);
    myForm.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="small-form">
    <form id="My-Form">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input id="Name" type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="hideForm(event)">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: He likely wants to hide the div.

Comment: Yeah. I added the solution based on that.

Comment: `small-form` is the div. See my answer

Comment: Yeah. I didn't do anything with the `div`. Just hid/removed the form inside the div. He might be having something else inside the `div`. So it's safe to not touch that `div` as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `display` style to none in the `hideForm()` function in javascript to hide the form.

But, because you are using a submit button on the form it will try to redirect when the submit button is pressed. A simple solution to this (if you don't want the form to actually be submitted) is to change the type of the input to `button` rather than `submit`.

```js
    function hideForm()
{
    document.getElementById('small-form').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="small-form">
    <form >
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="hideForm();">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think we already beat this one to death